# PDF files going offline on computer sleep

Tags: windows-7, pdf, adobe-acrobat

I store my valuable PDF files for reading on my home NAS drive. When I wake my netbook up, the file I had been reading before going to sleep goes offline even though it is accessible. The pages of the PDF are blank until I re-open the file.

I'm using Adobe Acrobat Professional on my both computers (Windows 7). Is there a way to keep the file online upon wake-up?

Comment: Right click and make the file always available offline. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-NZ/windows-vista/Working-with-network-files-when-you-are-offline

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Windows doesn't ask you for your permission and cuts network access all the time when the computer goes to sleep. Whether the PDF reading app keeps it in memory when it stops being accessible, and whether/how it reloads it when the connection is back, this all depends on the PDF app only, I believe.

So if you find nothing related to this in Acrobat settings, try a few other PDF reader apps. Adobe Reader, Adobe Reader add-in for Firefox, the integrated PDF reader in Google Chrome and Nitro PDF are some I can think off.

If they all have this annoying behaviour, there's a simple solution: run away from the problem by telling your computer not to sleep, but to only turn the screen off. That shouldn't give you any issues.

Or you can alternatively temporarily download a copy of the PDF file to your computer when you're going to read it. Then it just cannot be affected by network issues.